# query syntax issue upgrading to mysql 8 from 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have this sql query which worked in mysql server 5.7 but won't work after upgrading to version 8.0.12

```
SELECT sID, FNames, total, grade, h_score, l_score, stud_per_sub, RANK FROM 
(SELECT k.sID, concat(s.surName,'  ', s.firstName,'  ', s.oNames) AS 
'FNames', k.total, k.h_score, k.stud_per_sub, k.l_score, k.grade, @curRank 
:= if(@prevRank = k.total, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank, @incRank := @incRank 
+ 1, @prevRank := k.total FROM terminal_assessment k LEFT JOIN student s ON 
(s.studentID = k.sID), (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevRank := null, @incRank := 
1) r WHERE k.subj_TeacherID=:sid AND k.session=:sess AND k.classID=:cid AND 
k.term=:trm AND k.subid=:subject ORDER BY k.total desc) AS m;
```

It gives this error message

> (Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'from [select k.sID, concat(s.surName,'  ',
>   s.firstName,'  ', s.oNames) AS 'FName' at line 1)

each time i tried running it

Comment: Try remove the single quote tags from *FNames*.

Comment: @Martin ok i will correct that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted to fix some syntax errors that I encountered, skimming your code. Not sure if it'll make it work, but it's at least a start.

You should also format/indent your code so that it becomes more easily readable. It will also make the debugging easier, as the console will tell you exactly what line is the issue in the proper formated example.

```
SELECT
    m.sID, 
    m.FNames,
    m.total,
    m.grade,
    m.h_score,
    m.l_score,
    m.stud_per_sub,
    m.`RANK`
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        k.sID,
        concat(s.surName,'  ', s.firstName,'  ', s.oNames) AS FNames,
        k.total,
        k.h_score,
        k.stud_per_sub,
        k.l_score,
        k.grade,
        @curRank  := if(@prevRank = k.total, @curRank, @incRank) AS `RANK`,
        @incRank  := @incRank + 1,
        @prevRank := k.total
    FROM
        terminal_assessment k
    LEFT JOIN
        student s ON
        (s.studentID = k.sID),
        (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevRank := null, @incRank := 1) r 
    WHERE 
        @sid     := k.subj_TeacherID
    AND @sess    := k.session
    AND @cid     := k.classID
    AND @trm     := k.term
    AND @subject := k.subid
    ORDER BY k.total desc
) AS m;
```

I am at least not getting any syntax errors using this.

Comment: I just tried your code in the same format u suggested but still getting the same error in mysql workbench.

Comment: Try the updated answer, and see if you still get the same error @LoveJESUS. I don't get any syntax errors in my workbench, just that the table doesn't exist etc. So it should be a start.

Comment: I have included your edited code now and it's no longer giving the initial error message. however, the only challenge now is that it's not getting any record from the database as it ought to. @Martin

Answer (score 8):

RANK is a reserved word starting with MYSQL 8.0.2 (the version you upgraded to). That's the reason why you get the error.

To solve it is simple as adding backticks ` around RANK.

You can find more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R)
While trying to read mysql error messages you should always look at what is immediately before the point where the message starts from

Comment: Correct answer @Lelio

Comment: Thanks for help @Lelio

Comment: Thank you @Lelio